# jQuery updates page slow with .text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

First post on here so hello everyone :D

I have this web project I am working on and I wanted to go over and change my code all over to use more jQuery than regular HTML.

I have this line in my javascript file

```
document.getElementById("pizzaCounter").textContent = count.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits: 0});
```

And in trying to make it with jQuery and reading about it I transformed it into this

```
$("#pizzaCounter").text = count.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits: 0});
```

It does work.. but it takes a couple of seconds to update on the screen. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: jQuery `text` is a function .... `$("#pizzaCounter").text(newText)`

Comment: @charlietfl It seems I haven't done my resarch properly. Thanks for the answer my problem is solved now!